# How do I communicate with an application/program via USB

Tags: visual-studio, matlab, api, serial-port, usb

I have a program running on a small computer. For simplicity, let's say the program displays a string that says "adjusting" when adjusting and "ready" when ready. The manual for this program is sparse but says I can query this string by using the command "STATUS? " via serial interface. I have no idea what this means, so if someone could please give me a starting point that would be great. Essentially I would like to know how I could even send this query command to the software. I'm only marginally familiar with MATLAB, so if someone with experience with this type of communication could say what tools are necessary to write a loop that constantly queries the status and returns a logical when the program is "ready" that would be great.

Below is all I could find in the manual:
[Serial interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4feYR.png)
[command instructions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ilpvv.png)

Comment: You only mention one *"small computer"* (its physical size or processing capability is probably irrelevant) and a program.  You mention a *"serial interface"*, which would be a hardware port that is also one end of a serial link.  Such a *"serial interface"* is useless you establish a serial link using another compatible (at both HW and SW levels) serial port.  The *"manual"* (for the *"computer"* or the program?) mentions a RS-232, DB-9 connector assigned to COM2 on the "*Panel PC side"*.  Does the *"computer"* have such a connector?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. Yes, it has a USB port available. I found out I could query the application by connecting to this USB from my other computer and using the instrument control toolbox from MATLAB. I'm now figuring out how to incorporate this into a script that I can run a loop with to continually query this application at specific intervals. Then I will figure out how to send a signal from MATLAB to a signal generator to trigger an analog event. I'm just looking for compatible hardware and will post the results if/when it works. I will accept others' answers if there are any